# Directly writing to stdout of different process

Tags: c, unix

Is it possible to write directly to stdout of another process?

We have two separated processes A and B.
Process B should write to its stdout information from process A. I was looking into that and found the pipes... but the problem is that i don't really like the need to write from A and read from B at the same time (amount of information can be very big and pipes by itself are limited by system?) mostly because it can be too complex. And maybe it could be easier to write into file from A and then print this file into stdout from B...

UPDATE:
Process A is expected to be running constantly starting from system start-up(Unix)
Process B is expected to be executed from console and get information from process A.
Communication between processes are easy to implement in our environment. But since amount of information can be very big i wanted to make high-efficient way to get infromation from A to stdout of B

Comment: It's an oddly phrased question. If, for instance, you're running both your programs on the console without redirection, then they'll both have the same `stdout` - the console. If B is just going to print out what A sends it, why do you need B at all?

Comment: Can you use a thread in process B to read from the pipe and just print it right away?

Comment: In other words, you want process A to write directly to the stdout of process B? What platform(s) are you working with? Also, how are you outputting the information? stdout is usually line-buffered at least. As Paul stated, why is B necessary? Can you edit the question to explain the roles of the two processes? Does A generate information that B must process, and B outputs the information in a specific format? Can this same thing be done from within process A?

Comment: If writing directly to B's stdout would be a viable solution, then it seems B isn't doing any kind of processing of the output at all, and seems completely unnecessary.

Comment: I updated description. Process B should get to operator console(only stdout, not tty) information from process. Also process B is expected to deliver information and no processing is expected. Upon execution of process B it should only get information to stdout and exit. Also i'm sorry for a little vague question, but i'm investigation of how to get information from constantly running process in efficient way. Since this process is already started, we cannot receive output from this process directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may send `STDOUT` file descriptor (`1`) from **B** to **A** over *UNIX domain* socket connection.

You can do it [manually](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~eweiss/222_book/222_book/0201433079/ch17lev1sec4.html). Or you can use portable [library](http://www.normalesup.org/~george/comp/libancillary/).

In either case process **A** will receive file `STDOUT` descriptor of **B**. Then **A** can `write()` to it.

Comment: Thanks for tip, i will look into that. And sorry i'm still unable to make rep++

Comment: @Douman no worries, we're here to ask for help and give help ;)